# How to force download a file using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like the user to download a file when he/she clicks a '*download this file*' link.

**The use case:** A user clicks a link, and the web app generates a file and "pushes" it as a download.

I have the following PHP code. Although the file is being generated correctly in the server, it is not being downloaded (and not showing the download dialog box).

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile('file.zip');
```

I tried to add the following but it is not working:

```
header("Location: file.zip");  // not working
```

Although, I found a JavaScript solution (which is working), by trying the following redirect:

```
window.location.href = 'file.zip';
```

The problem is, doing the JavaScript thing above tries to "unload" the current window /form, which will not work for me in this situation.

Is there a solution to this using just PHP to "force" the file (in this case 'file.zip') to download?

Comment: `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is not a HTTP header. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file_url = 'http://www.myremoteserver.com/file.exe';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
```

Also make sure to add proper content type based on your file application/zip, application/pdf etc. - but only if you do not want to trigger the save-as dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I have two examples that I use and ***work***, well three actually.

HTML

```
<a href="save_file_1.php">Click here</a>
```

PHP (save_file_1.php)

```
<?php
$file = 'example.zip';

 if(!file)
 {
     die('file not found');
 }
 else
 {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit;
 }
?>
```

And the second, which is short and sweet.

A dialog box will prompt the user to save to...

HTML

```
<a href="save_file_2.php">Click here</a>
```

PHP (save_file_2.php)

```
<?php
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.zip');
readfile("example.zip");
?>
```

And a variant of the example just above:

```
<?php
$file = "example.zip";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
readfile("$file");
?>
```

All of which I have tested and working (for me) on a hosted server using PHP Version 5.4.20.

Comment: Thanks, this creates the file (like my example), but still tries to "unload" the current form. This means, Chrome or Firefox (or any browser) will show..."Are you sure you want to leave this page?" alert box.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll need to see your form or HTML then (all/full code), including any other PHP code that may be used in conjunction with your present/shown code. @Gandalf If you are using JS also in conjunction with my/your code, then that may be the fault. Something in your present code usage is causing this.

Comment: Addendum: I'm also using Firefox (latest version) and it did not generate that message, so it's obviously something to do with your unshown code/HTML. @Gandalf